# Spring data jedis connection pool configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, jedis

A quick impatient configuration for starter of Jedis in Spring is

```
<bean 
        id="jedisConnFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
        p:host-name="${redis.hostname}" 
        p:port="${redis.port}"
        p:use-pool="${redis.use.pool}"
/>
```

I understand that Jedis uses in backend the Apache common pool. However the pool configuration is something I can't figure out to configure by Spring DI in xml by looking at [JedisConnectionFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.java)

============ Update ===================

For the completeness, defining the solution.

```
<!-- Jedis Connection Pool configuration -->
    <bean
        id="jedisPoolConfig"
        class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig"
        p:maxTotal="30"
        p:maxIdle="10"
    />
<!-- Redis Connection Factory -->
    <bean 
        id="jedisConnFactory" 
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
        p:host-name="${redis.hostname}" 
        p:port="${redis.port}" 
        p:password="${redis.password}"
        p:use-pool="${redis.use.pool}"
        p:pool-config-ref="jedisPoolConfig"
    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another bean of class [JedisPoolConfig](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/JedisPoolConfig.java) (it extends apache `GenericObjectPoolConfig`) and set properties you need. Then set that bean into your `jedisConnFactory` with `p:pool-config-ref`.